# Use dictionaries to finish a python gradebook program with keys that are student names, and whose values are lists of student scores

Tags: python, dictionary, key

This isn't a 'graded' exercise in my class but it is practice to get to know the process for using dictionaries and all that goes with it. The book content itself is vague to say the least, and I am struggling to make this run. I get to the point where it will run, ask for entry, and throw an error after I enter a name/grade. Can someone point me in the right direction and tell me where I went wrong?

```
student_grades = {}  # Create an empty dict
grade_prompt = ("Enter name and grade (Ex. 'Bob A+'):")
menu_prompt = ("1. Add/modify student grade\n"
                "2. Delete student grade\n"
                "3. Print student grades\n"
                "4. Quit\n")

while True:  # Exit when user enters no input
    command = input(menu_prompt).lower().strip()
    if command == '1':
        name, grade = input(grade_prompt).split()
        student_grades.update({name, grade})
    elif command == '2':
        name, grade = input(grade_prompt).split()
        del student_grades
    elif command == '3':
        name, grade = input(grade_prompt).split()
        print(student_grades)
    elif command == '4':
        break
    else:
        print('Unrecognized command.')
```

Comment: For option 2 you need *del student_grades[name]* . For option 1 you'll need *student_grades[name] = grade* Is that where you're having a problem?

Comment: zybooks keeps throwing an error at me on the command line in the first if statement but when I run it in pycharm with the feedback given here to tweak the code I had, it will run as intended. I think my textbook is having a bad day.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! You're almost there with your approach.

I'll briefly outline the aspects that let your program fail:

- The `dict.update(...)` method requires a dict, but you are providing a set; you confused the colon `:` between name and grade with a comma `,` here.
- Deleting an entry of a dict requires to provide the key; your approach will delete the entire dict. Ask the user for input of `name` only, and omit the `.split()` when reading input - then use that `name` input to identify the key that should be deleted: `del student_grades[name]`
- Printing the dict's contents does not require input, you can safely delete that line where you ask the user for name/grade when printing the dict

In the end, you'd come up with code similar to this:

```py
#!/bin/python3

student_grades = {}  # Create an empty dict
grade_prompt = ("Enter name and grade (Ex. 'Bob A+'):")
delete_prompt = ("Enter name to clear:")
menu_prompt = ("1. Add/modify student grade\n"
                "2. Delete student grade\n"
                "3. Print student grades\n"
                "4. Quit\n")

while True:  # Exit when user enters no input
    command = input(menu_prompt).lower().strip()
    if command == '1':
        name, grade = input(grade_prompt).split()
        student_grades.update({name: grade})
    elif command == '2':
        name = input(delete_prompt)
        del student_grades[name]
    elif command == '3':
        print(student_grades)
    elif command == '4':
        break
    else:
        print('Unrecognized command.')
```

Comment: Thank you jbndlr! Your feedback helps! I didn't notice the comma error! Zybooks is still yelling at me, but it functions as intended in pycharm. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I added to the elif command 2 to delete the name and grade from the dictionary. If not, it just deletes the last entry. I hope this helps.

```
    student_grades = {} # Create an empty dict

    grade_prompt = "Enter name and grade (Ex. 'Bob A+'):"
    menu_prompt = ("1. Add/modify student grade\n"
                    "2. Delete student grade\n"
                    "3. Print student grades\n"
                    "4. Quit\n")

    while True:  # Exit when user enters no input
        command = input(menu_prompt).lower().strip()
        if command == '1':
            name, grade = input(grade_prompt).split()
            student_grades.update({name: grade})
        elif command == '2':
            print('Who do you want to delete?',student_grades)
            name = input()
            del student_grades[name]
        elif command == '3':
            print(student_grades)
        elif command == '4':
            break
        else:
            print('Unrecognized command.')
```